# Programming Arduino with avrdude within Eclipse- cannot find -l/usr/avr

Tags: eclipse, gcc, arduino, fedora

I am trying to program the Arudino Nano from Eclipse. It has the same processor as the Uno (Atmega328p). I have had this working before with the Uno, but have since gotten a new hard drive and had to reinstall/reconfigure everything. I am running Fedora 19 with Eclipse Kepler. I am getting an error in the build process that I don't even know where to start looking to solve, and Google hasn't been much help...

Here is the error:

```
make all 
Building target: Arduino_Template.elf
Invoking: AVR C Linker
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,Arduino_Template.map -mmcu=atmega328p -o "Arduino_Template.elf"  ./Analog.o   -l/usr/avr
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.2/../../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/usr/avr
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Arduino_Template.elf] Error 1

17:29:38 Build Finished (took 124ms)
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Or does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using a discrete Makefile. But that's just me >.>

Comment: I'm not that advanced...

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be described like this:

- First, the library should be specified only by its name and without the "lib" prefix and the ".a" suffix. The linker (this is where you get the error) will look for the library within the specified in the project paths and will add whatever is necessary to the file library name. So if the library you need is named `mystuff` it will look for a file named `libmystuff.a`.

In your case this is specified by the `-l/usr/avr` which I think could be misconfiguration or you did not copy/paste the entire error output. With the '-l' option you specify the name only, not the entire path to the file.

- Second, the path should be specified, in the project configuration, where to look for the libraries, otherwise the linker will look for the library files only within your own project only. Often libraries are part of another project - so you need to adjust the project configuration accordingly.

I had similar problem and this is how I solved it ...

Go to menu Project/Properties. On left - choose "C/C++ Build". On right - choose the tab "Tool Settings". On the tree view choose "AVR C Linker" then "Libraries" sub-item. You are where you may need to make changes.

- The list of "Libraries" is where you add libraries names, such as `mystuff`.
- The Libraries Path is where you specify the paths to the libraries. This may look like this: `"${workspace_loc:/mystuff/Release}"`

The result of this is that the linker will look for this file: `/mystuff/Release/libmystuff.a` under you workspace root folder.